# Arrange output of grouping method based on the values in outer list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Being newbie in pandas and actually in coding as well, I faced with some, I'm pretty sure, simple for most problem.

I got two dataframes. I need one column from both of them to get frequency table of column values. The frequency table of the first `df` is grouped by ascending. The problem is, that the second table must have the same order of values on the output as first `df`.

This makes me think that in such case I need to arrange the output for the second `df` using list of ordered values from first table.
But I do not know how to do it in right way.

For now I have the only these poor lines of code.

```py
df1 = Economics.groupby("Country")["Country"].count().sort_values()

keys = ['Equatorial Guinea', 'Haiti', 'Sweden']  #ordered list of countries from df1

countries = Economics1["Country"].unique().tolist()

diff = set(countries) - set(keys)
keys +=diff
```

I created countries variable in order to compare if there are new values in `df2` that are not in `df1`.

I also thought of using dictionary. But I do not know whether it's useful since keys and countries can be of different length. (although, If we are going to add values from countries to keys, maybe, its not a problem, I don't know)

What I want to get is the same order of variables in frequency table as `df1`.
Like
`df1` output is:

```
Equatorial Guinea            101  
Haiti                        202  
Sweden                       404
```

Then `df2` output is:

```
Equatorial Guinea            314  
Haiti                        218  
Sweden                       509  
Netherlands                  1019
```

Comment: What is `Economics1` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's the df2

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the answer was sooo close

I solved it in the next way:

```
 G = df1.groupby("Country")["Country"].count().sort_values()
 D = df2.groupby("Country")["Country"].count().sort_values()
 countries = df2["Country"].unique().tolist()
 keys = G.index.tolist()
 diff = set(countries) - set(keys)
 keys +=diff
 D = D.loc[keys]
```

But maybe there can be a more elegant way...